# Linq: Transforming specified column's datatypes and values while preserving unspecified columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Order` objects. `Order` has the properties: `int Id, decimal Price, string OrderNumber, string ShipperState, DateTime TimeStamp;`

I know which columns I want to transform (`Price`, `TimeStamp`) and I want to keep the other columns without needing to specify them.

This example is transforming specified columns but I still need to include the non-transformed columns.

```
var myList = model.Orders.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.OrderNumber,
    // decimal to string
    Price = x.Price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")),
    x.ShipperState,
    // DateTime to string
    TimeStamp = x.TimeStamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm")
}
```

If I were to add a column `string ShipperCity` to the `Order` class, I would like `myList` to also have that property without having to go back and update the projection.

An ideal answer would not rely on external libraries, reflection and only be a line or two.

Comment: Ideally you could materialize the `Order` objects as-is without the need for a projection, and add calculated read-only properties to the model to transform the data as needed.  This would have the added benefit that these calculated properties would always be available to any consuming code without having to write more projections.

Comment: I'd like to keep the same name - datatype and value would change but not the name. I am doubtful that what I want is possible but it "feels" like it should be doable in C#

Comment: Honestly it's sounding like the modeling doesn't match the use cases.  Perhaps you're looking for another model entirely which pulls data from a view, and the view internally projects the data?

Comment: If you don't want to have a projection (either creating anonymous objects or having another model with the desired property types and values) but you want to have new properties (e.g. `string ShipperCity`) automatically appear then you cannot avoid collecting the properties dynamically e.g. using reflection. And of course due to lack of a class with the desired types even with reflection you can only create anonymous objects that fit your need. I'd suggest creating e.g. `OrderDto` class with the desired property types and create a `ctor` that gets the original `Order` and does the projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to modify the model class as @David suggested you can write extension methods for it like this:

```cs
public static class OrderExtensions
{
    public static string GetFormattedPrice(this Order order)
        => order.Price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

    public static string GetFormattedTimestamp(this Order order)
        => order.Timestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm");
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

The effect of this alternative is that whereever you wanted to use the transformed `order.Price` and `order.Timestamp` there you have to use `order.GetFormattedPrice()` and `order.GetFormattedTimestamp()` respectively.

In the question it was not specified that **where the data come from** and **what type of application the data is used in**.

For example methods cannot be used in `XAML binding` and everywhere else where a property is required.

**Please note:**

In C# (almost) everything is strongly typed hence once the class and the properties in it are defined you cannot set one of its property value to a different type of data and also you cannot change the type of the property. So by default you cannot avoid projection when you need some transformation. If you need all the properties - either the original value or the transformed value - you have to list all of them in the projection.

**almost everything except `dynamic`**

You can actually transform the type and the value of a property but only if it is defined as `dynamic`. For example this works below:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    // Original: decimal; Converted: string;
    public dynamic Price { get; set; }

    public string ShipperState { get; set; }

    // Original: DateTime; Converted: string;
    public dynamic Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public static class OrderExtensions
{
    public static void Transform(this Order order)
    {
        if (order.Price.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
            order.Price = order.Price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

        if (order.Timestamp.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            order.Timestamp = order.Timestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var originalList = new List<Order>()
        {
            new Order() { Id = 1, OrderNumber = "1", Price = 100m, Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
            new Order() { Id = 2, OrderNumber = "2", Price = 200m, Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
            new Order() { Id = 3, OrderNumber = "3", Price = 300m, Timestamp = DateTime.Now }
        };

        originalList.ForEach(order => order.Transform());
    }
}
```

Although this example works there are some things to know:

- [`dynamic` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)
- This example looks like a hack, maybe it can be considered as a hack. :)
- In this example the original `Order` objects are changed not their projection/clone/etc.
- `dynamic` properties are not allowed in Entity Framework models as you cannot specify the SQL column type for them even using the methods of `DbModelBuilder`. I did not try it in other use-cases but it seems to be a very restricted possibility.
- For `dynamic` properties there is no IntelliSense, so after typing `order.Price.` no list would appear with any method or property.
- You have to use these properties very carefully as there is no compile-time check. Any typo or other mistake will throw an exception only during run-time.
- If this option somehow fits the needs it might be worth implementing the conversion of the `string` value back to the original type.

That's all the update I could add to my original answer. Hope this is an acceptable answer to your comment.

Comment: If you can edit your answer to say something to the effect of "You are limited to only projections in a purely linq solution and cannot include unspecified columns. Here is an alternative", I'll accept your answer.